# JayData vs Upshot (crossplatform HTML5 app)

Tags: html, cross-platform, hybrid, upshot, jaydata

I'm just in the planning phase of developing my iPhone/iPad/Android app.

Basically the app will query data from remote data sources and store it locally. As data management will be the key feature of this app, so the UI isn't an important factory in this case. I decided to develop a HTML5 and JavaScript-based hybrid application and deploy it with PhoneGap/Cordova.

I'm a .NET developer, I use Visual Studio 11 for web development, so I found the Single Page Application template, which uses Upshot.js by default.

By exploring the alternatives, I've found JayData http://jaydata.org library. It seems to me that it's something similar to upshot.js.

Could you share your opinion, which way should I go to build a cross-platform HTML5 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upshot and JayData looks similar but actually they are quite different, which makes your choice easier. There are  things however both provides

Both has pros and cons (as everything in life)

Upshot.js is backed by Microsoft and focuses mainly on oData + Knockoutjs support. It is included in Visual Studio. You can query oData endpoints with it using  a procedural query language.Upshot supports read/write operations, and also realtime updates.

JayData supports multiple datasources, among them are oData but also device local webSql as well, plus some other providers too. JayData let's you query oData or webSql on the same with, with sime JavaScript functions, so you dont have to learn sql and oData uri syntax. JayData provide read/write operations but realtime updates require a small user code.

Comment: I already have SQL-knowledge from enterprise .NET developments, writing SQL statements isn't a problem...but I'm happy that JayData  gives an API and I can avoid crazy string building in JS.